# Prefixing xml elements that are missing namespace

Tags: java, xml, namespaces

I am receiving some pregenerated xml document as a string and I need to prefix any xml elements where the prefix is missing. For example

input:

```
<a xmlns:b="http://www.b.com">
<element1>test</element1>
<b:element2>test</b:element2>
</a>
```

output:

```
<c:a xmlns:b="http://www.b.com" c="http://www.c.com">
<c:element1>test</c:element1>
<b:element2>test</b:element2>
</c:a>
```

I have the document parsed into a Node, but I can't figure how to add a prefix to any element that is missing a prefix. I was going to fall back on some regex string replacement, but I think this should be possible with the java xml api, I'm just stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT 1.0 transformation will move all no-namespace elements into a namespace with prefix="c", uri="http://www.c.com".

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='']">
    <xsl:element name="c:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.c.com">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0):

While Michael's answer is certainly a "proper" way to do it, if you want a simpler solution without XSLT for the XML at hand you could just replace `<a xmlns:b="http://www.b.com">` by `<a xmlns="http://www.c.com" xmlns:b="http://www.b.com">`. This introduces `http://www.c.com` as default namespace to be assigned to any element not having a namespace prefix explicitly. Note, though, that this isn't as generic as Michael's solution.

If you don't want to manipulate XML at the string level, you could parse and rewrite your XML as well, for example using Java's `XMLStreamWriter` class, and in particular the `setDefaultNamespace()` and `writeDefaultNamespace()` methods.